# Get facebook user cover photo via spring-social-facebook

Tags: java, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

Is there any way to get the user cover photo via `spring-social-facebook`?

Something similar to this (used to retrieve the profile picture);

- Via `AbstractConnection`, method [getProfileUrl()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/social/connect/support/AbstractConnection.html#getProfileUrl())
- Via `UserOperations`, method [getUserProfileImage()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/social/facebook/api/UserOperations.html#getUserProfileImage())

Thanks for the help

Comment: hi..does that help solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From version `2.0.x` you can get the cover image using

```
 facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile().getCover()
```

See [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/)

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for answering! I was using version `1.1.1.RELEASE` and this version hasn't this method. I did'nt realize that version `2.0.0.RELEASE` was released this April. Your answer works like a charm with the latest release, thanks for that!